# Elasticsearch / Storm integration methods

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-storm

Looking for a simple integration path between Elasticsearch and Apache Storm. Support for this is included in the elasticsearch-hadoop library, but this brings tons of dependencies on the Hadoop stack: from Hive to Cascading, that I simply don't need. Has anyone out there succeeded in this integration without bringing in elasticsearch-hadoop? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by integration in this case? What do you want to achieve? ES as input to Storm or Storm stores in ES ?

Comment: Both ways. I want to iterate a scroll from a spout, emitting tuples into various streams. Some bolts, in turn, will write into ES after processing. I am implementing pipelines in which ES is both source and destination. I am making some progress after addind the source ES connection for the spout into the setup function to ensure it is serialized before the topology is lauched.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use the [elasticsearch Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_maven_repository.html) or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: Correct. I am using the Java API. The question is what are best practices for high-throughput processing of ES data in Storm. I currently open a transport client on multiple Storm spouts, each reading from a scroll and emitting JSON tuples. Then every bolt has its own transport client connection - they batch up the incoming tuples and issue a bulk write periodically. This works, but the throughput is very low. I am looking into using ES node client connection instead to avoid the two-hop operations. Also disabling replicas in the target index during creation.

Answer (score 0):

In my project we're using [rabbitmq river](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/#river-rabbitmq) for indexing the storm output. It's very efficient and convenient way to write to elasticsearch. You basically put the messages to the queue and the river does the rest. If something gets stucked the data are simply buffered on the queue.

So I would say, use this river approach for writing and elasticsearch Java API for reading, like Kit Menke suggests (or the [Jest client](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest), we've found this cool and it offers async API basing on ApacheHttpAsyncClient, though we're not reading from elasticsearch in storm topology but in different services).

Comment: Thanks, very useful perspective. Sounds like you have a RabbitMQ cluster -- is it comparable in size to your ES cluster? if not, can you provide an idea of node ratios?

Comment: I have played around with worker counts, batch sizes (for bulk inserts on the bolts) and scroll sizes and no matter what I do throughput seems to stabilize around 1500docs/sec (~4KB/doc). There is plenty of unused CPU, memory and I/O capacity in both Storm and ES. The spout (source scroll) shows 'complete latency (ms)' as zero, which I assume means source documents are processed in under 1ms. Latency on the bolt's side (write to ES) is around 8ms, which seems rather high.